# VisualStudio PostBuild event copy failed

Tags: visual-studio, cmd

Im trying to copy the XAP file from the output dir to an external dir on my machine after a successfully build.

Here is the command I have used.

```
copy  $(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).xap "C:\wamp\www\slmedia\ClientBin\$(ProjectName).xap"
```

or this would be better

```
copy  $(OutDir)\*.* "C:\wamp\www\slmedia\ClientBin\*.*"
```

but its not working.

**Update**

The error I get is

```
Error   1   The command "copy  Bin\Debug\\*.* "C:\wamp\www\slmedia\ClientBin\*.*"
" exited with code 1.   EduFXRuntimeClient
```

**Solution**

Had to use another variable

```
copy  "$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).xap" "C:\wamp\www\slmedia\ClientBin\$(ProjectName).xap"
```

Comment: Does the first command work?  If so, why would you consider the second that's not working?

Comment: neither is working, I only need the XAP file but I guess copying all would be better

Comment: I would suggest the first solution in the event that you add more files to your project and you don't want to move everything. What's the ProjectName?  Do you need quotes around the first argument?

Comment: Ive tried bot with quotes an no quotes - Looking closer at the error I think I need another variable before $(OutDir). Looks like I have to reference the full dir